# Croppic, resizing images below container size

Tags: javascript, php, croppic

The Croppic library (http://www.croppic.net/) does not provide for zooming images below the container size. However, this can be solved by modifying the zoom() function in the library file:
https://github.com/sconsult/croppic/issues/100

I have tried doing this in various ways, using the information in this issue, but nothing works. I'm doing something wrong and I don't know what.

Example:
https://github.com/rudolphreti/croppic_example/

Example from github online:
https://srv19859.microhost.com.pl/croppic_example/

Comment: Given that Croppic is no longer supported and outdated, it seems reasonable to change the library to https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/ Or do you know of any better alternatives?

Comment: However, eliminating this small issue with Croppic would allow me to fully realize my current goal, so I'm not quite sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I consider the topic closed. I will use the library: https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

In this example my problem is solved:
https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/examples/fixed-crop-box.html